# Data validations not working in MVC4 website

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have model created with data annotations and in the partial view form when I click on submit client side validations does not work and form gets posted to the server. I am breaking my head over this from last couple of days. Following is the head section in _Layout.cshtml where I have included all the scripts

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    <link href="~/Images/yellowtribe3.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/themes/base/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/YellowTribes.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />        
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/menu3.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/rateit.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/shCore.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/shThemeDefault.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/prettify.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/rateit.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
            $.extend($.mobile, { ajaxFormsEnabled: true });
        });
    </script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

And following is the partial view code where I have inputs

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
    <tr>
        <td align="right" width="15%">
            <div>Name:</div> 
        </td>

        <td align="left"> 
            <div class="input200">
                <div class="input200">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name, new { @maxlength = "25" })</div> 
            </div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">
            <div>Comment:</div> 
        </td>
        <td align="left"> 
            <div>@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.CommentText, 5, 50, null)</div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha())
            @Html.ValidationMessage("recaptcha")
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
        </td>
        <td align="left"> 
                <input id="ArticleID" name="ArticleID" type="hidden" value="@ViewData["ArticleID"].ToString()" />
            <input class="actionButtons" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateInput();" formmethod="post"/> 
            <div id="thanksMsg" style="display:none; color:Red;">
                <b>Thank you for your comment...</b>
            </div>      
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <br /> <br />
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

If I view the source of my web page it seems to look fine with validations

```
                <div class="input200"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter your name" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" /></div> 
            </div> 

            <div><textarea cols="50" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter comments" id="CommentText" name="CommentText" rows="5">
```

Not sure why it just won't validate when I leave these fields empty. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue. The problem was with the way I have included javascripts scripts.
I changed following order
from

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your model code?

I did something really silly the other day that kept me stuck for a little while, I hadn't declared my properties correctly, I just created public strings instead of a property with a set and get method. Everything worked just fine when using the model except for the model binding and validation. It was driving me nuts, maybe you've made the same mistake?